# How to stop randomization if some condition is met

Tags: vb6

I am creating a quiz application in vb6. I have 5 questions which are available in different forms. I am randomizing these forms/questions. I am adding every question/form to list everytime it appear. How can I stop the randomization if those 5 question is already called?

**my code:**

```
Function randnum(ByVal lower As Integer, ByVal upper As Integer) As Integer
randnum = Int((upper - lower + 1) * Rnd + lower)
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim correct As Integer
Dim correct1 As Integer
Dim test As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
If Option3.Value = True Then
Form3Score.Text1.Text = Val(Val(Form3Score.Text1.Text) + 1)
Else
Form3Score.Text3.Text = Val(Val(Form3Score.Text3.Text) + 1)
End If
Start:
Randomize
Select Case randnum(0, 4)
Case 0

    Form3q1.Show
    Unload Form3q2
    Unload Form3q3
    Unload Form3q4
    Unload Form3q5
    Form3.Text1.Text = "Q1"
    test = False

    For i = 0 To Form3.List1.ListCount - 1
    If Form3.Text1.Text = Form3.List1.List(i) Then
  test = True
    GoTo Start
    End If

    Next

    If test = False Then
    Form3.List1.AddItem ("Q1")
    End If
Loop

Case 1
Do Until (Val(Form3Score.Text3.Text) + Val(Form3Score.Text1.Text) = 5)
    Form3q2.Show
    Unload Form3q1
    Unload Form3q3
    Unload Form3q4
    Unload Form3q5
    Form3.Text1.Text = "Q2"
    test = False

    For i = 0 To Form3.List1.ListCount - 1
    If Form3.Text1.Text = Form3.List1.List(i) Then
  test = True
    GoTo Start
    End If

    Next

    If test = False Then
    Form3.List1.AddItem ("Q2")
    End If
Loop
Case 2
Do Until (Val(Form3Score.Text3.Text) + Val(Form3Score.Text1.Text) = 5)
    Form3q3.Show
    Unload Form3q2
    Unload Form3q1
    Unload Form3q4
    Unload Form3q5
    Form3.Text1.Text = "Q3"
    test = False

    For i = 0 To Form3.List1.ListCount - 1
    If Form3.Text1.Text = Form3.List1.List(i) Then
  test = True
    GoTo Start
    End If

    Next

    If test = False Then
    Form3.List1.AddItem ("Q3")
    End If
Loop
Case 3
Do Until (Val(Form3Score.Text3.Text) + Val(Form3Score.Text1.Text) = 5)
    Form3q4.Show
     Unload Form3q2
    Unload Form3q3
    Unload Form3q1
    Unload Form3q5
   Form3.Text1.Text = "Q4"
    test = False

    For i = 0 To Form3.List1.ListCount - 1
    If Form3.Text1.Text = Form3.List1.List(i) Then
  test = True
    GoTo Start
    End If

    Next

    If test = False Then
    Form3.List1.AddItem ("Q4")
    End If
Loop
Case 4
Do Until (Val(Form3Score.Text3.Text) + Val(Form3Score.Text1.Text) = 5)
    Form3q5.Show
    Unload Form3q2
    Unload Form3q3
    Unload Form3q4
    Unload Form3q1
    Form3.Text1.Text = "Q5"
    test = False

    For i = 0 To Form3.List1.ListCount - 1
    If Form3.Text1.Text = Form3.List1.List(i) Then
  test = True
    GoTo Start
    End If

    Next

    If test = False Then
    Form3.List1.AddItem ("Q5")
    End If

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: pls disregard the do loop. i tried it but its not functioning

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much more easily with just one form, and shrink your existing code by about 80% while you're at it.

Put each of your questions (i.e. the contents of each of your existing forms) in a separate Frame.  (Best way to do this is highlight all the elements on a form, select the frame--make sure you do this--and hit Paste.) Make the frames a control array (give them the same name, set the Index property from 0 to 4).  To show a given question, you will make it visible and make all the other frames invisible. Start with all 5 frames invisible.

Now, make a dynamic (i.e. resizable) array (I'll call it x here: `Dim x() as Integer:ReDim x(0)` will initialize it; put the two statements on separate lines rather than separating them with a colon as I have it here). This will hold the values of the questions that have already been asked.

To get a test question, first get a random number between 0 and 4.  Add an element to x (`ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x)+1)`). Store the value in the newly-added element (use `x(UBound(x))=yourRandomNumber`), which will evaluate to the last element in the array).  The first time through, make the frame with the index that is the same as your current random number visible.

On subsequent questions, get a random number as before.  Then iterate x and see if the value is already there (`for i = 0 to UBound(x)`, etc.).  If it is, get another random number.  When you get one that isn't in array x already, make the previous frame invisible (look up the previous frame's index in x--`x(UBound(x)-1)`--or iterate the entire frame array and make each of them invisible), and make the frame with the index that is the same as the current random number visible.

Rinse and repeat until you've asked all 5 questions (`UBound(x)=4` once you've asked them all).  (Note: the examples of how to use UBound might not be perfect, since I haven't fully tested them, but if you experiment a bit you should be able to work out any mistakes I may have made. UBound evaluates to the number of the highest array element.)